# How to fetch a data from parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I want to pass the value of text retrieved from view in controller to database. Parameters retrieved from view are

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Bj5gJR1GKO7JSeJpdrV72T5FoX283rTH8L7NfIiyRFM=", "project"=>{"comments_attributes"=>{"9"=>{"text"=>"commenting", "user_id"=>"1", "category"=>"---"}}, "id"=>"9"}, "submit"=>"SUBMIT"}
```

And I am trying to fetch text using the following:

```
:data => params[:project][:comments_attributes][params[:id]][:text]
```

but I am getting an error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

What I am getting is not prohibiting me from doing it when I used the same expression on other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive there is something wrong with your parameters, but if you overlook that, i think you could do a small correction:

```
data => params[:project][:comments_attributes][params[:project][:id]][:text]
```